# how to divide list

Tags: php, jquery

```
<ul><h2>More useful stuff... </h2>
<li><a href="#">category 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 8</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 9</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 10</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 11</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 12</a></li>
</ul>
```

how can I auto divide this using jquery

like

```
category 1     category 6      category 11
category 2     category 7      category 12
category 3     category 8
category 4     category 9
category 5     category 10
```

or could i use php either way is fine

sample code here http://jsfiddle.net/3CRnh/

Comment: So you want to make 5 categories per column? You can do that with either a table or floating divs. It is too trivial.

Comment: yes, so this could not be achieved using list?

Comment: try something like this done on http://jsfiddle.net/ddrXY/

Comment: yes It can you just need proper css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/3CRnh/1/)**

you should use `.slice`, from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div)

```
var li = $("ul > li");
$('li').unwrap();
for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i+=5) {
 li.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll("<ul class='left'></ul>");
}
```

Comment: can this be done automatically, like auto divide it into 2 columns and not manually add numbers to divide the list

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan, for that you can use jquery plugin https://github.com/weblinc/jquery-columnlist or use css3  `column-count: 2;` check this artical http://alistapart.com/article/css3multicolumn

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically divide your list into how many column as you want using CSS:

```
ul {
    column-count:3; -moz-column-count:3; -webkit-column-count:3; 
    column-gap:2em; -moz-column-gap:2em; -webkit-column-gap:2em;
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3CRnh/2/

Comment: how can I do that without modifying the html?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? You don't need to modify anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use divs and CSS for it

```
<ul><h2>More useful stuff... </h2>
    <div class="a">
          <li><a href="#">category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >category 5</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
          <li><a href="#">category 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 9</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 10</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
          <li><a href="#">category 11</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">category 12</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the CSS to format it:

```
.a,.b,.c{
    float:left;
    padding-right:50px;
}
```

Just try this demo I have created at http://jsfiddle.net/DehYQ/.

​

Comment: but Im getting the list in a category list widget in wordpress, so i cannot modify the list structure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want 5 categories per column and your categories where in an array you could use php:

```
<?php
$categories = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12); // my made up category array
echo '<div style="float:left">';
foreach($categories as $k=>$category){
    if($k%5==0 && $k!=0){
        echo '</div><div style="float:left">';
    }
    echo '<li><a href="#">category '.$category.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</div>';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visit the link, there is, they give the great example for break the our list in equally parts

Link is here

Click Here