# Using jQuery on commented HTML

Tags: html, comments, lazy-loading

I'm using https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any on a page, like this:

```html
<div class="lazyload">
  <!--<div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="item-container"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>-->
</div>
```

I found a [jQuery script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938495) that I modified to automatically add the .lazyload class container around every 4 .item-container divs to break them up.

The problem is that for the lazy load plugin to work, the HTML inside the .lazyload container has to be commented out. Therefore, the jQuery doesn't add the .lazyload container. Is there any way to have jQuery modify commented out HTML?

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzw4Lh2e/1/).

Comment: Do you want the commented out HTML to remain commented out after you modify it? Or to be readable HTML again?

Comment: It would have to remain commented out for the lazyload plugin to work, I assume. So, yes.