# Wrapping around <li> tags around divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

**At the moment**, I have a sequence of 9 divs loaded into a container div:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
   <div class="testdiv"></div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve the following with jQuery: Making a list out of these divs with an li element around every three divs. So **my desired outcome** is the following:

```
<div class="container">
       <ul>
          <li>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
             <div class="testdiv"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I have already tried this, but failed:

```
var target = $('.container');
var testdivs = $('.testdiv');
var counter = 0;

target.prepend('<ul>');
target.append('</ul>');

testdivs.each(function() {
  var currentDiv = $(this);

  if (counter % 3 == 0) {
     target.prepend('<li>'); 
  }

  if ((counter+1) % 3 == 0) {
     target.append('</li>');
  }

  counter ++;
});
```

If anyone could provide a jsfiddle with a solution I would really appreciate this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3366539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var $div = $(".container div");
for (var i = 0; i < $div.length; i += 3) {
  var $li = $("<li/>");
  $div.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll($li);
}
$( ".container" ).wrapInner( "<ul></ul>>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mxqn3voh/)**