# re build ul and li tag with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to find the way to split ul tag by showing only 10 li tag per ul.

Suppose I have li 30 elements. script will be re build into 3 ul and each ul has 10 li tag.

How can I do this ?

suppose original is :

```
<ul id="ul1" style="">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Adidas</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>jason markk</span></a></li>
    <li>... 28 mores </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery will re build ul in to 3 ul (10 li per ul):

```
<ul id="ul1" style="">
    <li>10 times</li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul2" style="">
    <li>10 times</li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul3" style="">
    <li>10 times</li>
</ul>
```

Please guide,
Thanks

Comment: what did you try with jquery?

Comment: duplicate ul and put 10 li tag on each ul

Comment: then show us the code....

Comment: Iterate over `li`s in original list. While they exist, generate a new `ul` and attach first 10 `li`s to it. Finally, delete original list, now empty

Comment: @Ryo, please check the answers below, and accept the answer which helped you. So that this question won't be left unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
var n = 5;
var uls = $("#ul1 li").length / n;
for (i = 0; i < uls; i++) {
    var newUl = $("<ul/>", { id: "ul" + (i + 2) });
    $("ul").eq(i).after(newUl);
    newUl.append(newUl.prev().find("li:gt(" + (n - 1) + ")"));

}
```

Change the value of `n` according to your need

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/56r05wrm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var lis = $("ul > li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=20) {
    lis.slice(i, i+20).wrapAll("<ul id='ul"+(parseInt(i)/20+1)+"'></li>");
}
$("ul > ul").unwrap();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amjx3sLn/)**

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
var no=$("#ul1").children().size();
var count=0,tmpstr='';
for(var j=0;j<no;j++)
{
  if(count<10)
  {
      tmpstr=tmpstr+"<li>"+$("#ul1 li:nth-of-type("+(j+1)+")").html()+"</li>";
      count++;
 }

 if(count==10 || j==(no-1))
 {
     $(".uj").append("<ul>"+tmpstr+"</ul>");
     tmpstr='';
     count=0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

```
var parent = $(".container");
var items = parent.find("li");
var ul = $("<ul/>");
var counter = 0;
for (; counter < items.length; counter++) {
    if (counter > 0 && counter % 10 === 0) {
      parent.append(ul);
      ul = $("<ul/>"); // new list
    }
    ul.append(items[counter].detach());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`.nth-child(10n)`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** to iterate over each 10th element.

```
$("#ul1 li:nth-child(10n)").each(function(){
   $(this).prevAll('li').andSelf().wrapAll('<ul/>') 
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0x2mvbam/1/)**

**Edit** :

```
$("#ul1 li:nth-child(10n)").each(function(i){
    $(this).prevAll('li').andSelf().wrapAll($('<ul/>',{ id: 'ul'+(i+1)})) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var liLength=$("li").length;
for(var i=0;i<liLength;i=i+10){
     $("li:eq("+i+"),li:gt("+i+"):lt("+(i+9)+")").wrapAll( "<div id=ui"+(i/10)+" />");
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9k3r8y2y/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

thks for your answer  :) .

I also just get the solution here's what im doing:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var itemindex = 0;
        var Jlistobj = null;
        $('#list li').each(function()
        {
            if (itemindex % 10 == 0)
            {
               Jlistobj = $("<ul></ul>");
            }
            Jlistobj.append($(this));
            $('#out_div').append(Jlistobj);
            itemindex++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create separate functions for chunking array and displaying objects, something like:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function(chunkSize) {
    var array=this;
    return [].concat.apply([],
        array.map(function(elem,i) {
            return i%chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i,i+chunkSize)];
        })
    );
}

renderUl = function(items) {
    var ul = $('<ul>');
    $.each(items, function(i, item){
        var li = $('<li>');
        li.html($(item).html());
        li.appendTo(ul);
    });
    return ul;
}

var items = $('#original li').toArray();
var chunked = items.chunk(10);

var output = $('<div />');

$.each(chunked, function(i, items){
    output.append(renderUl(items));
})

$('#original').replaceWith(output);
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a31jujpz/)

chunk function shamelessly taken from [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

Using an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30972330/1338292), you could group those elements together like so:

```js
$.fn.every = function(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += n) {
        arr.push(this.slice(i, i + n));
    }
    return this.pushStack(arr, "every", n);
}

var id = 1; // current id
$('#ul1 > li')
  .slice(10) // skip first ten
  .every(10) // group every ten thereafter
  .each(function() {
    // create new <ul> and place after the last one
    $('#ul' + id)
      .after($('<ul>', {id: 'ul' + ++id}).append(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul1" style="">
  <li><a href="#"><span>Adidas</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>jason markk</span></a></li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>

  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
  <li>... 28 mores </li>
</ul>
```