# Converting "i+=n" for-loop to $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below `html` structure:

```
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
```

Now to group/wrap each 4 items in a separate `div` I did as below:

```
var div=$('.thumbnail');
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i+=4) {
  div.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
};
```

**My question - Is there any way to convert this specific loop into `$.each` or is `for loop` only the way to do this?**

**UPDATE**

> This ain't duplicate because the answer mentioned there using jquery
>   `$.each` doesn't work as expected and that has been specific to
>   wrapping `divs` may be on any technique and my question is specific to
>   wrap with `$.each`. I don't see it as duplicate!!

A **[Pen](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/mJBvYE)** to show how the `$.each` answer over there works!

Comment: Isn't it simply [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13279336/1338292)?

Comment: In this case a for loop will be the better choice

Comment: @Ja͢ck Oh yea!! But that's kind of plugin we need to create right? Isn't there any simple way? I mean jquery makes the life of developer easier so was thinking was there any replacement for this kind of loops in jquery!

Comment: @ArunPJohny.. So no optional replacement for this using `$.each`

Comment: `$.each` is simply the wrong tool for custom iteration :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck.. Hmm I see.. might expect some right way from jQuery developers in their upcoming versions.. :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck.. Even that does not work - **[Pen here](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/mJBvYE)** :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap every 3 divs in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao You can do this http://jsfiddle.net/Lcr4Lund/

Comment: Great @ShaunakD!! That's one Damn great answer!! Can you post it please!! :)

Comment: @Manoz. You can see this **[pen](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/mJBvYE)**!! that's not working either!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A jQuery only way would be to iterate over the `nth-child(4n)`

```
$('.thumbnail:nth-child(4n)').each(function(){
    $(this)
      .prevAll('.thumbnail').andSelf()
      .wrapAll($('<div/>',{class:"new"})) 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcr4Lund/)**

Considering the complexity, not sure whether the `prevAll()` performs better than the plain for loop.

Referring one of my **[similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30935701/3639582)**

Comment: Simply superb!! Thanks for enlightening!! :)

Comment: On a small document you probably won't see much difference, but introducing this complexity to eliminate a humble for-loop doesn't seem worth it; also, what if the elements are wrapped with elements that share the same class name, it would not work in the same way all of a sudden.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The above solution is case-specific. *if the elements are wrapped with elements that share the same class name*: This can still be handled jQuery-selector way (`('.thumbnail:not('.thumbnail > .thumbnail')`). But again as you said, jQuery might increase the complexity compared to a plain for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really beats a direct `for` loop like that, but it would be handy to keep this in a small extension:

```
$.fn.wrapEvery = function(n, html) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i+=n) {
        this.slice(i, i+n).wrapAll(html);
    }
});
```

Then, called like:

```
$('.thumbnail').wrapEvery(4, "<div class='new'></div>");
```

Or, a more generic chunk function from an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30972330/1338292).

```
$.fn.every = function(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i+=n) {
        arr.push(this.slice(i, i+n));
    }
    return this.pushStack(arr, "every", n);
}
```

Called like:

```
$('.thumbnail').every(4).wrap('<div class="new"></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!! a `plugin` would be a great idea too!! Thanks for your effort and explanation!! +1