# Create new row every 4 "thumb divs"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what im trying to achieve is to put every 4 divs inside new created row

Heres my html input

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

and i want it to look like

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I started with

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var thumb = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');
if (thumb.length < 4) {

}
</script>
```

but i have no idea how to go on from this point

Comment: If these div's are loaded dynamically using php then try the php way to solve it.

Comment: @VigneshBala what suggests that the OP is using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $(".container .thumb");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=4) {
        divs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
    }
});
```

For more details [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div)

Comment: Any chance twose two divs could have separate clasess?

Comment: Yes change .thumb into div