# How to add div with class every second item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help..
How to add div with class every second item.
I have a list item:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add div with class every second item:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 double-product">
        <div class="product rotation">
            <div>data 1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="product rotation">
            <div>data 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 double-product">
        <div class="product rotation">
            <div>data 3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="product rotation">
            <div>data 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to add div with class every second item.
Thank you.

Comment: You mean to want to wrap every two divs into a single div with class `double-product` right?

Comment: Did you mean second child or first child?

Comment: Possibly duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the output provided in your code, use the following.
This uses [**`wrapAll()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) in a loop.

```js
products = $('.product');

for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i+=2) {
  products.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-12"><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 double-product"></div></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product rotation">
        <div>data 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```