# How to wrap the nth to nth element in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this:

```
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
<div class="myTest"></div>
```

and I am trying to get:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
</div>
<div class="holder">
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
    <div class="myTest"></div>
</div>
```

using jQuery. I have tried using `nth-child`, but then it wraps every element with that div instead.

I am trying to get **every 5 elements** into a `div` called *holder*.

Although that, I am trying to use **"nth to nth" element** approach. In other words, it is NOT an assumption that every 5 element is wrapped, but rather 1st-to-5th element wrapped in one `div`, and perhaps 6th-to-14th element in another. And let's assume these 2 batches are both wrapped with the same class, `holder`.

Any dynamic way to batch these up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div use this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using `each()` and `wrapAll()`,

```
var tmp = $();
$(".myTest").each(function(i){
  tmp = tmp.add(this);
  if(((i+1) % 5) == 0){ 
    tmp.wrapAll("<div class='holder'>"); 
    tmp = $(); 
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jrv36gme/2/)

Comment: `.holder
{
  border:1px solid black;
}` will make it appear better!

Comment: Good one! Have never encountered this method earlier :)

Comment: This nailed it!! Although, if you could have a look at my edit and give another approach, that would completely win this question. Thanks loads :)

Comment: @Sina Can you explain about your new requirement a bit? I cannot understand.

Comment: What if I want to have a random pattern of the same class `divs`s to be wrapped together e.g. from **6th-to-14th** element. While that, keep your current answer for the case where there is a certain pattern (every 5 in our case).

Comment: @Sina How will you supply that random pattern via an array or something?

Comment: Nope it's just a random number as my intention. I would want to wrap 6th-to-14th element all together. Feel free to take any other example.

Comment: @Sina You can do it like https://jsfiddle.net/jrv36gme/3/

Comment: Thanks mate! nailed it :)