# Wrap every x elements into a div, then (after x wrap) wrap a different number of elements (for x wrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

Is it possible to create this kind of loop?

For example : Wrap every 2 divs into a div, then (after 2 wrap) wrap every 3 divs (for 3 wrap)

```
<div id="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="container">
<div class="group">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have already found the classic method on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div?rq=1)

```
var divs = $("div > div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
}
```

Any ideas please?

(I'm a beginner so sorry if i get it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The step as in `i += step` should be a variable 2, and you should increment it on each iteration:

```js
var divs = $("div > div");
var step = 1; // the step 
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += step) { // increment i with the step
  divs.slice(i, i + step + 1).wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>"); // slice for i to i + step + 1 and wrap
  step++; // increment the step
}
```

```css
.group:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.group:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I'm trying to apply your solution but I'm not familiar with this. My divs fit into each other. Can you explain the different variables? Or show an example with two steps?

Comment: The only difference between this and your code, is the step variable (instead of the fixed step - 3) which is incremented. I've added comments in the code.