# jQuery to wrap a predetermined set of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Question

What are ways to add dynamic elements to wrap list items and apply a class?

### Current research

I found [this](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) on the official docs from jQuery.

Which gave an example

```
<script>
    $( "span:nth-of-type(2)" )
    .append( "<span> is 2nd sibling span</span>" )
    .addClass( "nth" );
</script>
```

But that only discussed adding a class to an individual element. I want to wrap multiple elements

## Default code with generated items

```
<ul>
    <!-- These items will be dynamically generated-->
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
    <li>Sixth</li>
</ul>
```

What the current code would produce

[image]

## Desired outcome

```
<ul>
    <div class="row">
        <li>First</li>
        <div class="right">
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">
            <li>Fourth</li>
            <li>Fifth</li>
        </div>
        <li>Sixth</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

What the desired code would produce (CSS styling defined elsewhere)

[image]

Comment: if the wrapping pattern is going to be the same and not random then how about using the `documentFragment` to avoid the multiple reflow and improved performance too.

Comment: The HTML of the desired outcome is invalid

Comment: As you see you can chain `append()` method, so add all your elements, and then apply class on desired selectors.

Comment: @j08691 so probably better to just have all `<div>` as opposed to `<li>`s?

Comment: `.wrapall()` is probably the function you're looking for.

Comment: @Barmar from what I have found so far. I can wrap all of the same elements like `$( "p" ).wrapAll( document.createElement( "div" ) );` but i have a gap in information for then wrapping specific numbered items.

Comment: `$("p").slice(0, 3).wrapAll("<div>")` will wrap the first 3.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div/3366539#3366539