# wrapping elements in a new div

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have the below html:

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
        Content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in jQuery if I am to wrap every 3 elemnts in a new div like below how could I do that?

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
            Content here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried slice and wrap which did not really help me. Any ideas? appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var entries = $('#one > .two > div.entry');

entries.each(function(i) {
    if( i % 3 == 0 ) entries.slice(i,i+3).wrapAll('<div>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PZkSL/

Comment: RightSaidFred: Thanks a ton for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [How to wrap every 3 child divs with html using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432201/how-to-wrap-every-3-child-divs-with-html-using-jquery) or [Wrap every 3 divs in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the div element with class "two", and iterate through it's children. When you find the first child use $(firstChild).before('`<div>`'); and on the third child use $(thirdChild).after('`</div>`'); Just iterate all the way through using this method. Haven't used .before() or .after() so not sure how this will pan out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would just write a simple `for` loop, something like:

```
var two = $(".two");
var elements = $(".entry");
var group = [];
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  var mod = i % 3;
  if(mod == 0 && group.length > 0) {
    var container = $('<div></div>');
    two.append(container);
    for(var j=0;j<group.length;j++) {
      container[0].appendChild(group[j]);
    }
    group = [];
  }
  group[mod] = elements[i];
}
```