# Jquery .after() not inserting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

**EDIT: Solution found [How to wrap every 3 child divs with html using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432201/how-to-wrap-every-3-child-divs-with-html-using-jquery/1432455#1432455)**

---

I'm printing a list with a lot of `<div>`'s and want to insert a `</div><div class="clearfix">` after every 6th `<div>` with jQuery.

Naturally that would be something like

```
$('#staffscroll .person:nth-child(5n)').after('</div><div class="clearfix">');
```

But the output becomes `<div class="clearfix"></div>` which just doesn't make sense.

Any thoughts?

---

**Ok, maybe should provide some more code..**

I'm working with a slideshowscript. The whole take is basicly to put stuff in a `<div>`.

For example..

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="clearfix"> First slide wrapper
        <img>
        <img>
        <img>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> Second slide wrapper
        <img>
        <img>
        <img>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> Third slide wrapper
        <img>
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm working with a CMS aswell, which havn't got that much control over dynamic output. So my thought was that I just could output all the content, and then provide the slide-wrappers afterwards.

Therefore the `</div><div class="clearfix">`

Havn't got a clue if it makes any more or less sense now, but I hope you get what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `<div class="clearfix"></div>` makes perfect sense. it's `</div><div class="clearfix">` that doesn't make sense (invalid html).

Comment: @Shurdoof  it does make sense if the whole "list of divs" is already wrapped in a "clearfix div" I think the OP wants to close the first div and start a new one (like rows in a table?), whether it's possible doing it this way I don't know

Answer (score 4):

The statement you try to insert isn't correct XML. You are thinking about your HTML document as a big string, but this is the wrong way to do if you want to use tools like jQuery.

I suggest you to learn more about [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and how to use it. Your whole approach is wrong, so your sample of code isn't correctable.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, jQuery parses the string to a DOM fragment and then inserts it. When your `</div><div class="clearfix">` is parsed it's assumed the `</div>` is an error, and it also closes the `<div class="clearfix">`. Therefore the effect you observed.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `after` isn't modifying the HTML -- it's creating new DOM elements and adding them to the document.  You should use `wrapAll` to wrap a group of elements.  My guess is that your code will look something like this:

```
var start = 0,
    $list = $('#staffscroll .person').slice(0, 6);

while ($list.length) {
    $list.wrapAll('<div class="clearFix"></div>');

    start += 6;
    $list = $list.end().slice(start, start + 6);
}
```

[jsFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aEL87/)

Comment: Well, that sent my code into some endless loop, but I think that's sort of what I'm looking for.

Comment: And then i just found a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432201/how-to-wrap-every-3-child-divs-with-html-using-jquery/1432455#1432455

Answer (score 0):

**As I replace the .wrapAll for .append or a similiar?**