# How can I split a list of <p> using js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of tag `<p>`

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<p>Paragraph 6</p>
<p>Paragraph 7</p>
<p>Paragraph 8</p>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
<p>Paragraph 11</p>
<p>Paragraph 12</p>
<p>Paragraph 13</p>
```

I have nth paragraph, and want to divide them into 2 part in order to style them differently in `<div>` tag. How can I do that
e.g:

```
<div class="Top">
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<p>Paragraph 6</p>
</div>
<div class="Bottom">
<p>Paragraph 7</p>
<p>Paragraph 8</p>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
<p>Paragraph 11</p>
<p>Paragraph 12</p>
<p>Paragraph 13</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not have a clear direction. Don't know where can I start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376256/jquery-wrap-every-x-elements-in-div

Comment: @Rory Crossan it's not a duplicate, the OP is trying to group by division and not in a each x element. Also the suggested duplicate question is about "between" elements -  Should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`wrapAll`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```
var $els = $("p");
var len = $els.length;

$els.slice(0, len / 2).wrapAll($("<div class='top' />"));
$els.slice(len / 2, len).wrapAll($("<div class='bottom' />"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like following

```
var length = $('p').length;
$('p').slice(0,length/2).wrapAll("<div class='Top'></div>");
$('p').slice(length/2,length).wrapAll("<div class='Bottom'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:lt()` , `:not()`

```js
var p = $("p"), len = p.length;

$("body").prepend("<div class=Top></div><div class=Bottom></div>");

$(".Top").append($("p:lt("+ Math.floor(len / 2) +")"));
$(".Bottom").append($("p:not(.Top > p)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<p>Paragraph 6</p>
<p>Paragraph 7</p>
<p>Paragraph 8</p>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
<p>Paragraph 11</p>
<p>Paragraph 12</p>
<p>Paragraph 13</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you do a lot here is a more advanced approach which add a jQuery function called `makeGroups()`.

**Demo**: [**JSnippet**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/618/A-jQuery-plugin-for-grouping-elements-with-class-names)

**The Plugin**:

```
$.fn.makeGroups = function(n,c) {
    c = c || [];
    n = n > 0 ? n : 1;
    len = this.length;
    l = Math.floor(len / n);
    l += (len - l * n > l)?1:0;
    pc = "", p = 0, t = l;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t += (len - l < t)?len - l:0;
        gclass = (typeof c[i] != 'undefined')?c[i]:pc;
        this.slice(p,t).wrapAll("<div class='" + gclass + "'></div>");
        p = t, t = l + p, pc = gclass;
        if (t > len) break;
    }
    return this;
};
```

**Usage**:

```
$('body p').makeGroups(2,["Top","Bottom"]);
```

**Definition and Behavior**:

Takes two arguments `n, c` the first argument indicates how many groups you want. The second is a class name array which will be added to each group.

- `n` default is 1;
- `c` is optional and if not set no class will be added.
- If `c` is smaller than the number of groups the last class will be used for the undefined class names.
- If the elements don't divide exactly with the number of groups then if the remainder is bigger than the group size the group size will be extended - otherwise the last group will be extended and will include the remainder.