# Using .wrap() for each x amount of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrap every 3 divs in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div)
>   [jQuery - use wrap() to wrap multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements)

Lets say I have 4 divs, as below:

```
<div class="section">1</div>
<div class="section">2</div>
<div class="section">3</div>
<div class="section">4</div>
```

I would like to use `$('.section' [increments of 2] ).wrap('<div class="row"></div>')` so each 2 `div.section`'s will be wrapped with `div.row`, so the end result would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="section">1</div>
  <div class="section">2</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="section">3</div>
  <div class="section">4</div>
</div>
```

How is this done?

Comment: Exactly the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432201/how-to-wrap-every-3-child-divs-with-html-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.section:even').each(function(){
        $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="row">');
});
```

Based on [jQuery - use wrap() to wrap multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements)